# Remove integers at the start of multiple line

Tags: java, string, integer

I've a `txt` file having over thousand line of text that has some integers at the starting.
Like:

```
22Ahmedabad, AES Institute of Computer Studies
526Ahmedabad, Indian Institute of Managment
561Ahmedabad, Indus Institute of Technology &amp; Engineering
745Ahmedabad, Lalbhai Dalpatbhai College of Engineering
```

I want to store all the lines in another file without the integers.
The code I've written is:

```
while (s.hasNextLine()){
    String sentence=s.nextLine();
    int l=sentence.length();
    c++;
    try{//printing P
        FileOutputStream ffs = new FileOutputStream ("ps.txt",true);
        PrintStream p = new PrintStream ( ffs );
        for (int i=0;i<l;i++){
            if ((int)sentence.charAt(i)<=48 && (int)sentence.charAt(i)>=57){
                p.print(sentence.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        p.close();
    }   
    catch(Exception e){}
}
```

But it outputs a blank file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of things in your code that should be improved:

1. Don't re-open the output file with every line.  Just keep it open the whole time.
2. You are removing all numbers, not just numbers at the beginning - is that your intention?
3. Do you know any number that is both `<= 48` and `>= 57` at the same time?
4. `Scanner.nextLine()` does not include line returns, so you'll need a call to `p.println()` after every line.

Try this:

```
// open the file once
FileOutputStream ffs = new FileOutputStream ("ps.txt");
PrintStream p = new PrintStream ( ffs );

while (s.hasNextLine()){
    String sentence=s.nextLine();
    int l=sentence.length();
    c++;
    try{//printing P
        for (int i=0;i<l;i++){
            // check "< 48 || > 57", which is non-numeric range
            if ((int)sentence.charAt(i)<48 || (int)sentence.charAt(i)>57){
                p.print(sentence.charAt(i));
            }
        }

        // move to next line in output file
        p.println();
    }   
    catch(Exception e){}
}

p.close();
```

Comment: I want to remove all the numbers. My text file has numbers only at the start of each line, which I want to remove.

Comment: Haha...I was scratching my head all over a `&&` for one hour..thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply this regular expression to each line that you read from the file:

```
String str = ... // read the next line from the file
str = str.replaceAll("^[0-9]+", "");
```

The regular expression `^[0-9]+` matches any number of digits at the beginning of the line. `replaceAll` method replaces the match with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

On top of mellamokb comments, you should avoid "magic numbers".  There's no guarantee that that the digits will fall within the expected range of ASCII codes.

You can simply detect if a character is a digit using `Character.isDigit`

```
String value = "22Ahmedabad, AES Institute of Computer Studies";

int index = 0;
while (Character.isDigit(value.charAt(index))) {
    index++;
}
if (index < value.length()) {
    System.out.println(value.substring(index));
} else {
    System.out.println("Nothing but numbers here");
}
```

(Nb dasblinkenlight has posted some excellent regular expression, which would probably easier to use, but if you're like, regexp turns my brain inside out :P)